# Magento2: How to changed products filter

Tags: magento2, filter

Now the products filter looks like this:
[image]

Anyone have solution how to to in this way? (filter in button).

[image]

Comment: that's not a button. that's a selectbox

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake. I mean select box.